# Remove Sub Queries from Select Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query where I need to pull back data from 3 tables, but there are some grouping that need to happen.  I know sub-queries are horrible, but I cannot seem to get this done any other way.  This is going to fall apart when there are tens and tens of thousands of rows.  Maybe I am over complicating this?  I tried "partition by", but that is going to pull back all the rows from ERT1, which would mess up the counts.  I could not use a group by since if I group on ERT1, it's going to mess up ER1.

I am using FK's and Indexes on the joined fields.

Anyone have any thoughts on this??

It would be much appreciated!!

```
SELECT ER.EventRegistrationID, DC.DiscountCodeID, DC.DiscountAmount, DC.DiscountCode, DC.ActiveFlag,

    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ER1.EventRegistrationID) 
        FROM T_EventRegistration ER1 
        WHERE ER1.DiscountCode = DC.DiscountCode
        AND ER1.EventID = DC.EventID
        AND ER1.OrderCompleteFlag = 1),0) AS NumTimesUsed, --includes refunded orders

    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ERT1.TicketNumber) 
        FROM T_EventRegistrationTickets ERT1, T_EventRegistration ER1 
        WHERE ER1.EventRegistrationID = ERT1.EventRegistrationID 
        AND ER1.DiscountCode = DC.DiscountCode
        AND ER1.EventID = DC.EventID
        AND ER1.OrderCompleteFlag = 1
        ),0) AS NumTicketsSold --excludes refunded tickets

FROM T_DiscountCodes DC, T_EventRegistration ER
WHERE DC.DiscountCode *= ER.DiscountCode
AND DC.EventID = 20188
AND DC.DeleteFlag = 0
AND DC.HiddenFlag = 0
AND ER.OrderCompleteFlag = 1
ORDER BY DC.DiscountCode, NumTimesUsed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or by creating derived tables

```
SELECT ER.EventRegistrationID
     , DC.DiscountCodeID
     , DC.DiscountAmount
     , DC.DiscountCode
     , DC.ActiveFlag
     , ISNULL(a,NumTimesUsed,0)
     , ISNULL(a2.NumTicketsSold,0)
FROM T_DiscountCodes DC, T_EventRegistration ER
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(ERT1.TicketNumber) NumTimesUsed
        FROM T_EventRegistrationTickets ERT1, T_EventRegistration ER1 
        WHERE ER1.EventRegistrationID = ERT1.EventRegistrationID 
        AND ER1.DiscountCode = DC.DiscountCode
        AND ER1.EventID = DC.EventID
        AND ER1.OrderCompleteFlag = 1) a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(ER1.EventRegistrationID) NumTicketsSold
        FROM T_EventRegistration ER1 
        WHERE ER1.DiscountCode = DC.DiscountCode
        AND ER1.EventID = DC.EventID
        AND ER1.OrderCompleteFlag = 1) a2
WHERE DC.DiscountCode *= ER.DiscountCode
AND DC.EventID = 20188
AND DC.DeleteFlag = 0
AND DC.HiddenFlag = 0
AND ER.OrderCompleteFlag = 1
ORDER BY DC.DiscountCode, NumTimesUsed
```

Comment: I have not seen this function before - this is very cool.  I assume this is much faster than a sub query?  It's really performing the same concept, hence why I ask.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how much it helps in your query tho, learned about it some days ago. You should check this talk out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m426WYclz8

Comment: That's a good video.  thanks for sharing!  This does seem to be much faster.  I dropped in to my production server - let's see how it performs!  Thanks again

Comment: This didn't replace subqueries...you still have them in your code. You should look at the execution plan and not just drop code in production to see how it does. Here are a couple of excellent articles on the topic of APPLY. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/ and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/

Comment: I know - i did test it out and it was much faster.  Not really sure why, but at least my pages are not timing out anymore. :)  Open to other ideas besides this answer.